# Is there a way to make specific JS not run on certain pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Soo Im using DNN and have multiple portals in one instance, with DNN you use modules that have there own scripts working over all portals.

So if I change the module JS it could potentially break that module for say 200+ sites (don't really want to go through every site to make sure it still works)

Anyway I have incountered a conflicted with a module's JS file and my JS file Ive just written, all I want to know is there a JS referrence that will stop certain JS files to not run on specific pages?

So far I have -thanks to nnnnn

`if (!$("#skin_wrapper").hasClass("donotrun")) {
!function(e,t,a,o){function s(t,a){ .... //jscript here
}`

Doesnt seem to be working, im not too sure what im doing wrong

Comment: You can include conditional code in a module so that it only runs if the current page has a certain class on its `<body>` tag, or *doesn't* run if the current page has a certain class, but then you still need to change a number of your pages that include that module to add the class. When you say "specific pages", how have you identified those pages?

Comment: Pretty much there is only one page I want the module JS not to run and instead my JS file to run. I can add anything to this specific page. (sorry im not that great with explaining myself) - although I do like the sound of the module JS not running via a certain class on the page

Comment: So change the module to *not* run if the class is specified with something like `if ($("body").hasClass("do-not-run"))` (or whatever), and then add that class just in the one page and include your second JS just in that page.

Comment: Is this correct?
`if(!$("body").hasClass("dontrunjs")){
!function(e,t,a,o){function s(t,a){va...... 
}`
it shouldnt load with the page that has class "dontrunjs"

Comment: Start using namespaces, they will help you to avoid this kind of issues in future.

Comment: @sarinjacobsunny sorry could you explain more, youve just made a point rather than explaining why. Also i still dont know what im doing wrong.

Comment: I used to work in IBM WebSpherePortal. There were cases where we had to use different instances of same portal in one single page. There we had encountered issues like if I click a button, it will affect all the portals. Also what ever actions happen, it will ruin other portals. So we looked for options and found namespaces. We did defined all functions and variables under a namespace variable so that it did the job for us.